# Is using a private bridge a suitable alternative compared to a VPN for connecting to Tor entry nodes?

Tags: bridge, vpn, private

I am a Tor newbie and considering deploying my own private bridge to connect to the Tor network.  Normally I would connect to Tor via a VPN to prevent the entrance node from knowing my clearnet IP but after reading about private bridges, I am considering dropping the VPN method all togther. What are the benefits/drawbacks of using a private bridge over a VPN? For example security, speed etc... .

Also is it possible to chain bridges? For example `Bridge -> Bridge -> Bridge -> TOR`

Many thanks

Comment: Comparing a tor bridge and a VPN is sort of like comparing a sofa and a bicycle.  The answer is just yes.  They're not at all the same thing once you get past the fact that they both involve computers.  Oh and yes you can chain bridges.  You can't watch netflix on tor.